# The New Facebook Request Dialog

Tags: facebook

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=88364 Tried this,but how can i access the 'data' field from request receiving end.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the latest documentation. The post you are looking at is really old and I believe refers to the 1.0 version of the Request Dialog. Facebook release 2.0 early this year and has updated it twice since then.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/569/

There announcement of 2.0 https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464